# How to union 2 regex expression?

Tags: regex, grep

I have two regex expressions:

1) `egrep \\.$`./lab1.txt  - returns a lines ending with a dot

2) `egrep '^\w+[aeiou]\b'` ./lab1.txt - returns a lines where the first word ends with a vowel

I need to join this expressions. So, I need to return a lines ending with a dot AND where the first word ends with a vowel. How can I do this?

My demo txt file (lab1.txt):

```
Hello world
Hello world.
London is the capital of GB.
Oslo is the capital of Norway
Oslo is the capital of Norway.
```

So, the final expression should return:

```
Hello world.
Oslo is the capital of Norway.
```

Comment: Why not use `^\w+[aeiou]\b.*\.$`?

Comment: Why is the best solution posted as an unexplained comment instead of a proper answer? Reminder: this is a "Q&A" site.

Answer (score 1):

Don't combine the regexes.  Pipe the output from one invocation of `egrep` into another invocation of `egrep`.

```
egrep '\.$' ./lab1.txt | egrep '^\w+[aeiou]\b'
```

Comment: No reason to run it twice when it can be solved with a single expression. `^\w+[aeiou]\b.*\.$`

Comment: Sure there's a reason to run it twice.  If it's clearer to express it as two different regexes, then that is a perfectly valid reason to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question:

You can use a lookahead-assertion:

- Match any line (`^.*?$`)
- Match any line ending with a dot (`^.*?\.$`)
- but only if it's preceeded by a first word wovel: `(?=^\w+[aeiou]\b)^.*?\.$`

All together:

```
(?=^\w+[aeiou]\b)^.*?\.$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/5mvw9pTZSiRTQM1h)

(requires multiline mode, if the whole input is a single string, not sure if egrep is working line-wise, but would assume it.)

Comment: I don't think I'd repeat the starting anchor.  The lazy quantifier will only slow performance with no added benefit.  `^(?=^\w+[aeiou]\b).*\.$`  If the first word is `I` or `A`, then maybe use `\w*`.